# Warn when install Angular cli via npm in global scope

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I’m using 9.6.1 version of node, it goes with 5.6.0 version of `npm`.

I’m trying to install `Angular` with follow command:

`$ npm i --no-optional -g @angular/cli`

But is returned the follow message: `npm WARN sass-loader@6.0.6 requires a peer of node-sass@^4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.`

I have installing `node-sass` like this:

`$ npm i --no-optional -g node-sass@^4.0.0`

And it installs well.

So I run `$ npm i --no-optional -g @angular/cli` again, but the warning continues.

If I installing without `-g` flag, everything happens well, but I need to install globally to use `ng` command.

Comment: Did you try to install node-sass locally ?

Comment: Yeap, I did. It installs. But that doesn`t solve my problem. I need to install globally the ```Angular```.

Comment: Try to  install locally, then in package.json add new row to "scripts" section like   "scripts": { "ng-serve": "ng serve"
  },     and run it 'npm run ng-serve'

Comment: @AlexanderPoshtaruk actually I used ```"bin": {"ng": "<.../@angular/cli/bin/ng>"}``` in ```package.json``` file, so I run ```$ npm link``` inside folder of this ```package.json``` to make a ```symlink``` in global scope. It works. But to use ```ng new```, for example, the ```package.json``` file don’t can have ```dependencies``` key.
Thanks.